# iphone settings password

Tags: iphone, settings

I have to secure some settings in my app,
how can I make the access to the settings password protected?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a settings bundle to integrate with the Settings application, this is not supported functionality (see [Implementing Application Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html) in Apple's iOS Application Programming Guide).

Comment: hello, yes Im using the settings bundle, working already, but I was wondering if is possible to use a password to access the app specific settings, cheers

Comment: No, it is not possible. If you want to password protect your application's settings you will need a custom settings screen.

Answer (score 1):

MaKo,

If I understand correctly you want to save a password securely. To save the password securely, you should save it to the keychain, using the `Security.framework`

Fortunately, there is a great wrapper for the iPhone Keychain. It's called `SFHFKeychainUtils`.

You can get it [here](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security).

You can find some more info [here](http://gorgando.com/blog/tag/sfhfkeychainutils) too.

-David

Comment: hi, thanks a lot!, is not what I needed but I will have a look at this Security.framework for other password needs tnx again!